# .NET 6 PDF page by page to one high PNG or JPG file - Converter in 2023

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, itext7

Guys i started implementation of PDF Converter. I need to convert for example 15pages of PDF to one, high PNG/JPG file, to use OCR tools that are prepared for it.

My problem is that techniques that i found on Stackoverflow and Github are outdated. I can't use most of methods, and im dizzy becuase of that.

All i have finished is below code, and it works for classic pdf's like generated invoices etc. PDF that result is in my attachment is like something i can't share here, but you can see result. Text is broken, its moved to the right i think and most of document can't be read.

```
public byte[] PdfToImage(byte[] pdf)
        {
            var reader = Docnet.Core.DocLib.Instance.GetDocReader(pdf, new PageDimensions(2.0));
            var pages = new List<byte[]>();
            int pageCount = reader.GetPageCount();
            int totalByteLength = 0;
            int fillHeight = 0;
            int fillWidth = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x <= pageCount - 1; x++)
            {
                var page = reader.GetPageReader(x);

                var width = page.GetPageWidth();
                if (width > fillWidth)
                {
                    fillWidth = width;
                }
                var height = page.GetPageHeight();
                fillHeight += height;
                var img = page.GetImage();
                pages.Add(img);
            }
            foreach (var p in pages)
            {
                totalByteLength += p.Length;
            }
            byte[] totalImage = new byte[totalByteLength + 100];
            int lastIndex = 0;
            foreach (var p in pages)
            {
                p.CopyTo(totalImage, lastIndex);
                lastIndex += p.Length + 1;
            }
            using (var doc = new Bitmap(fillWidth, fillHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
            using (var bmps = new Bitmap(fillWidth, fillHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
            {
                AddBytes(bmps, totalImage, 0);
                for (int y = 0; y < bmps.Height; y++)
                {
                    bmps.SetPixel(bmps.Width - 1, y, bmps.GetPixel(bmps.Width - 2, y));
                }
                Graphics gg = Graphics.FromImage(doc);
                gg.FillRegion(Brushes.White, new Region(new Rectangle(0, 0, fillWidth, fillHeight)));
                gg.DrawImage(bmps, new Point(0, 0));
                gg.Save();
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    doc.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    return stream.ToArray();

                }
            }

        }
```

[image: scanned PDF]

Do you have idea what should i do? I even don't save these images i use it as byte[] and

Answer (score 0):

Try a library like [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET)

**Note: this requires ghostscript to be installed**

As far as I understand your question, this code does exactly what you want. It merges multiple pdf files into one jpg image:

```cs
using ImageMagick;

var pdfs = new List<string> { "1.pdf", "2.pdf" };

using var imgList = new MagickImageCollection();
var settings = new MagickReadSettings
{
    Density = new Density(300, 300)
};
foreach (var pdf in pdfs)
{
    var coll = new MagickImageCollection(pdf,settings);
    foreach (var img in coll)
    {
        imgList.Add(img);      
    }
    //imgList.AddRange(coll); -> doesn't work
}

using var vert = imgList.AppendVertically();

vert.Write("result.jpg");
```

If you have just one pdf the code gets even simpler:

```cs
var settings = new MagickReadSettings
{
    Density = new Density(300, 300)
};
using var imgList = new MagickImageCollection("1.pdf",settings);
using var vert = imgList.AppendVertically();

vert.Write("result.jpg");
```

Comment: PDF isn't an image format and Magick.NET doesn't work with it by itself, it requires Ghostscript, a separate tool. A PDF is a package containing print instructions, specifically PostScript instructions

Comment: I do no understand what your comment is trying to say. I installed the nuget package tried my code with pdf files and it does what the question asks it to do. Maybe the variable names are chosen inappropriately, but the code still works and is enough for a mockup

Comment: You are right. I have that installed on my system and didn't read that in the docs. If it is possible to install it for the author of the question then this could be a solution. I'll edit my answer. Thank you.

Comment: hi, thanks @schgab but i tried it and i think that resources mandatory to this lib are not free for commercial use.